# Apply resizable image on canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas

Currently I am trying to make possible for a image to be drawn on a canvas using the jQuery Drag and Drop function. I have tried this.

```
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<br>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:128px;height:128px;" id="wrapper">
    <img id="ico" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/mustache.png" />
</div>
```

And JS

```
$('#wrapper').draggable();
$('#ico').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
});
$('#c').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('#wrapper').dblclick(function () {
            var img = $('#ico');
            var ctxt = $("#c")[0].getContext("2d");
            var offs = $("#c").offset();
            var uiPos = img.offset();
            var x = uiPos.left - offs.left;
            var y = uiPos.top - offs.top;
            ctxt.drawImage(img[0], x, y);
            $('#wrapper').remove();
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem I am facing is that when the image is resized it's not applied with the new size.
Here is the code in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MZpJ6/2/ . The above code is modified from other answers from the site, but I don't want to spam other people's questions, so I am making a new one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/uxNSN/

**You can resize the image drawn to the canvas using the optional sizing arguments on drawImage**

```
drawImage(theImage,x,y,width,height);
```

Here's how to get the new width/height to use in drawImage

**Save the resized dimensions in the .resizable's resize event**

```
// first save a reference to the wrapper div

var $wrapper=$("#wrapper");    

// then save the new size in the .resizable's resize event

$('#ico').resizable({

    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
    resize:function(event,ui){
        $wrapper.newWidth=ui.size.width;
        $wrapper.newHeight=ui.size.height;
    },
});
```

**Then you can use drawImage's resizing arguments in the .droppable's drop event:**

```
$('#c').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('#wrapper').dblclick(function () {
            var img = $('#ico');
            var ctxt = $("#c")[0].getContext("2d");
            var offs = $("#c").offset();
            var uiPos = img.offset();
            var x = uiPos.left - offs.left;
            var y = uiPos.top - offs.top;
            ctxt.drawImage(img[0], x, y,$wrapper.newWidth,$wrapper.newHeight);
            $('#wrapper').remove();
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to achieve.